# How to convert data.frame to (flat) matrix?

Tags: r

How can I convert the data.frame below to a matrix as given? the first two columns of the data.frame contain the row variables, all combinations of the other columns (except the one containing the values) determine the columns. Ideally, I'm looking for a solution that does not require further packages (so *no* `reshape2` solution). Also, no `ftable` solution.

```
(df <- data.frame(c1=rep(c(1, 2), each=8), c2=rep(c(1, 2, 1, 2), each=4),
                  gr=rep(c(1, 2), 8), subgr=rep(c(1,2), 4, each=2), val=1:16) )

c1 c2 gr1.subgr1 gr1.subgr2 gr2.subgr1 gr2.subgr2
1  1   1          3          2          4
1  2   5          7          6          8
2  1   9         11         10         12
2  2  13         15         14         16
```

Comment: there's always the base function `reshape`, I've never been smart enough to understand the arguments to it, but I'm also not a glutton for pain so I usually use `reshape2` for it's consistency and ease of use. YMMV

Comment: reshape and reshape2 are written in base R, so if you want to use their approach without loading the package, just extract the function content (eg. type acast and copy the function content)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an interaction variable to construct the groups:

```
newdf <- reshape(df, idvar=1:2, direction="wide", 
            timevar=interaction(df$gr,df$subgr) , 
            v.names="val", 
            drop=c("gr","subgr") ) 
names(newdf)[3:6] <- c("gr1.subgr1", "gr1.subgr2", "gr2.subgr1",  "gr2.subgr2")
 newdf
   c1 c2 gr1.subgr1 gr1.subgr2 gr2.subgr1 gr2.subgr2
1   1  1          1          2          3          4
5   1  2          5          6          7          8
9   2  1          9         10         11         12
13  2  2         13         14         15         16
```

Comment: +1 - had not seen / I forgot about `interaction()`. Probably a much better route than constructing it manually.

Comment: This works, thanks DWin. I built it in my original problem. I have a data.frame of exactly the same type (as shown by `str()`). The problem is that I obtain `Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , timevar) : undefined columns selected`, not sure what's wrong...

Comment: Can you make it have that error with a small subset and then post dput output? (I just ran it again in a fresh session and got no error.)

Answer (score 2):

Alright - this looks like it does mostly what you want. From reading the help file, this seems like it should do what you want:

```
reshape(df, idvar = c("c1", "c2"), timevar = c("gr", "subgr")
        , direction = "wide")
   c1 c2 val.c(1, 2, 1, 2) val.c(1, 1, 2, 2)
1   1  1                NA                NA
5   1  2                NA                NA
9   2  1                NA                NA
13  2  2                NA                NA
```

I can't fully explain why it shows up with NA values. However, maybe this bit from the help page explains:

```
timevar 
the variable in long format that differentiates multiple records from the same 
group or individual. If more than one record matches, the first will be taken.
```

I initially took that to mean that R would use it's partial matching capabilities if there was an ambiguity in the column names you gave it, but maybe not? Next, I tried combining `gr` and `subgr` into a single column:

```
df$newcol <- with(df, paste("gr.", gr, "subgr.", subgr, sep = ""))
```

And let's try this again:

```
reshape(df, idvar = c("c1", "c2"), timevar = "newcol"
        , direction = "wide", drop= c("gr","subgr"))

   c1 c2 val.gr.1subgr.1 val.gr.2subgr.1 val.gr.1subgr.2 val.gr.2subgr.2
1   1  1               1               2               3               4
5   1  2               5               6               7               8
9   2  1               9              10              11              12
13  2  2              13              14              15              16
```

Presto! I can't explain or figure out how to make it not append `val.` to the column names, but I'll leave you to figure that out on your own. I'm sure it's on the help page somewhere. It also put the groups in a different order than you requested, but the data seems to be right.

FWIW, here's a solution with `reshape2`

```
> dcast(c1 + c2 ~ gr + subgr, data = df, value.var = "val")
  c1 c2 1_1 1_2 2_1 2_2
1  1  1   1   3   2   4
2  1  2   5   7   6   8
3  2  1   9  11  10  12
4  2  2  13  15  14  16
```

Though you still have to clean up column names.

Comment: Interesting! I had used the `paste("grp","subgrp")` method to `reshape()` in my early days of R and thought it seemed odd then. You've convinced me I wasn't crazy and that I should probably learn to use `reshape2` instead.

Comment: The version with `dcast` is indeed nice. One can also use `acast`.